# How to force spring boot to log to the container via SLF4J?

Tags: spring-boot, wildfly, logback, slf4j

I have a spring boot application running on Wildfly 10 that I wish to "force" logging through the container. The ultimate goal is to control logging via standalone.xml config having org.springframework.* with INFO level and my own code as DEBUG level. After many SO questions and googling the best solution I achieved is:

- My own code logs correctly and is "captured" by the container.
- Spring framework is always in DEBUG and ignores whatever is defined in the container root logger.
- org.hibernate.SQL is always in DEBUG and also ignores the application server.
- I always get the spring auto-configuration report.

My configuration so far is:

```
<!-- Handlers and formatters ommited for brevity --> 
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
    <add-logging-api-dependencies value="true"/>
    <use-deployment-logging-config value="false"/>
    <logger category="com.arjuna">
        <level name="INFO"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
        <level name="INFO"/>
    </logger>
    <logger category="org.jboss.logging" use-parent-handlers="false">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <logger category="MYAPP" use-parent-handlers="false">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="MYAPP"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
    <root-logger>
        <level name="INFO"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
            <handler name="FILE"/>
        </handlers>
    </root-logger>
</subsystem>
```

As for the POM I followed many answers here to try and remove any trace of spring logback implementations and forcing it to use SL4J. The ideia was to exclude commons-logging and starter-logging packages for every spring-boot-starter.

I ommited some packages for space, but even my own utility jar's ommit those two artifacts in their own POM's (for each used starter).

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also, I have tried using jboss-deployment-structure.xml, albeit to no avail. Current configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="logging" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logging.jul-to-slf4j-stub" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
            <module name="org.jboss.logmanager.log4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j" />
            <module name="org.slf4j.impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I also checked the final maven build and:

- jcl-over-slf4j is present
- SLF4-API is NOT present.
- jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final is present (added via hibernate 5 dependencies)

I think I'm missing something obvious but I can't understand what it is. What might it be?

Thank you.

Comment: FWIW you shouldn't need the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. Maybe do a `mvn dependency:tree` and examine if Spring is bringing in logback or another log manager. You also shouldn't need `org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I removed the XML, the jcl-over-slf4j and checked the final WAR to verify that no jars pertaining to SLF4J or Logback are present. However the problem remains

Comment: I would just have to guess that Spring Boot is somehow overriding logging or configuring another log manager.

Comment: Yes, that  is also my opinion. I eventually managed to get hibernate to behave, but spring refusses to play along.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: I don't remember all the changes, but adding <logger category="org.hibernate.SQL" use-parent-handlers="false"><level name="WARN"/></logger> to force that specific category to WARN was a necessary step. Also, you'd have to remove any trace of debug in the properties: debug=false
logging.level.org.springframework.boot=WARN
logging.level.org.hibernate=WARN
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=WARN
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
org.jboss.logging.provider=slf4j

Comment: Also, please add to wildfly the following:  <use-deployment-logging-config value="false"/> and <property name="org.jboss.logging.provider" value="slf4j"/>.
It's messy